# anastr issue - why the speedView does not show up in the studio layout editor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm using 1.3.0.

The code runs as expected but why don't I see the object in the layout editor? I've tried with RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout.

When I use a library what is the magic for integrating a specific project widget in the layout editor?

I've tried clean project, sync with gradle and build.
Something is missing?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView
    android:id="@+id/speedView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: just for testing replace `"wrap_content"` in your `<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView`  with some `"100dp"`, is there any difference?

Comment: no difference. I wonder what the ? means in the component tree (snapshot)?

Comment: what `?` do you mean ?

Comment: look at the snapshot: in the component tree where it shows the speedView object. There is a ? which makes me think that I miss something in the integration. Same in the 'add object', I search for SpeedView but it doesn't find it?

Comment: integration? in `<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView` move your mouse to `SpeedView` part and do `Ctrl-left click`, does it go to `SpeedView` sources?

Comment: yes. it points to: public class SpeedView extends Speedometer {

Comment: so it is seen by android studio, what about just placing SpeedView inside simple FrameLayout?

Comment: Lol. Good idea. I was so much focus in seeing the object that it didn't get to my brain! Thanks so much!

Comment: thanks for what? is it seen when using `FrameLayout`? if so, you have to add some constraints when using `ConstraintLayout`...

Comment: that was the part that I made too complex. as you say I add it under a FrameLayout, and then it works nicely and I can add constraints. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: aha, ok, your welcome

Comment: @narb, can you add your working code snippet, even after put the Speedview in framelayout, no luck

Answer (score 0):

this is an old bug has been fixed in the next few versions, please anyone still have this issue move to the [latest release](https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView/releases/latest).